# dataset has a categorical response column in R using H2O deep learning package

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

I think, I have a datacasting problem using H2O platform in R.

this is the error:

> Error: water.exceptions.H2OModelBuilderIllegalArgumentException: Illegal argument(s) for GBM model: GBM_model_R_1568616391145_4.  Details: ERRR on field: _validation_frame: Test/Validation dataset has a categorical response column 'gold' with no levels in common with the model

and this is the code:

```
library(h2o)
kd_h2o = h2o.init(nthreads = -1)
data = readxl::read_excel("C:\\Users\\frzd\\Desktop\\mtx.xlsx")
data_order <- data[order(data$gold),]
data_order$gold=h2o.asfactor(data_order$gold)
Split_ts = .2
Split_vl = .1
indx <- 1:round(length(data$gold)*Split_ts)
ts <- max(indx)
ts <- round(indx*length(data$gold)/ts)
test = as.h2o(data_order[ts,])
train = data_order[-ts,]
indx <- 1:round(length(train$gold)*Split_vl)
ts <- max(indx)
ts <- round(indx*length(train$gold)/ts)
valid = as.h2o(train[ts,])
train = as.h2o(train[-ts,])

fit <- h2o.gbm(y = 15, 
              training_frame = train, 
              validation_frame=valid,
                    # cvControl = list(V = 5),
               )
```

could you guys help me out? :)

Comment: Hi Farzad. Welcome to So. That is not easy to help you without a minimum reproducible [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: It will be difficult to help you without any information about your data. However, I think you messed up the train/validation/test split by first ordering the data by the gold column. The levels (as the error says) are not the same for the training and the validation set.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

it's because of the wrong use of the data frames.
here is the corrected code:

```
# initializing the H2O service via internet
h2o.init(nthreads = -1)

# data preperation
data = readxl::read_excel("C:\\Users\\frzd\\Desktop\\mtx.xlsx")
data_order <- data[order(data$gold),]
data_order=h2o.asfactor(data_order)

# data split
Split_ts = .2
Split_vl = .1
indx <- 1:round(length(data$gold)*Split_ts)
ts <- max(indx)
ts <- round(indx*length(data$gold)/ts)
test = as.h2o(data_order[ts,])
train = data_order[-ts,]

indx <- 1:round(length(train$gold)*Split_vl)
ts <- max(indx)
ts <- round(indx*length(train$gold)/ts)
valid = as.h2o(train[ts,])
train = as.h2o(train[-ts,])

# perform fitting
fit <- h2o.gbm(y = 15, 
               distribution= "gaussian",
              training_frame = train, 
              validation_frame=valid
                    # cvControl = list(V = 5),
               )
```